# "Lake shore", "sea coast" and "river side" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

What do you call these three things in Spanish?

> - lake shore
> - sea coast
> - river side

Here are my suggestions:

- lake shore = orilla del lago
- sea coast = costa de mar
- river side = lado del río

Am I right?

Thank you.

Comment: En Chile usamos _borde_ en los tres casos. Parece que es correcto, pero me suena más a regionalismo.

Answer (score 3):

Curiosamente, puedes usar "costa" para las tres:

> **[costa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B6AEyOw)**
>
> Del gall. o cat. *costa*, y estos del lat. *costa* 'lado, costado', 'costilla'.
>
> 1. f. Orilla del mar, de un río, de un lago, etc., y tierra que está cerca de ella.

Sin embargo, yo usaría "costa" para la orilla del mar ("sea coast"). Para "lake shore" tu propuesta está bien, y para "river side" yo diría "orilla del río" o "[ribera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WRvSDST) del río".

Answer (score 2):

También puedes usar "orilla" en los tres casos.

Also you can use "orilla" for all.